# How can i check with onclick props is faster than redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-state

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { emotionCard } = useSelector((state) => state.selectedReducer);
const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

const selectId = props.id
const emotionId = emotionCard.selectId
// const emotion

const handleClick = (e) => {
    dispatch((selectEmotionAction({selectId})));
    console.log(selectId, emotionId)
}

if (props.id === "joy"){
    return (
        <SelectBox onClick={handleClick} check={check}>
            <SelectBox_Left>
                <img src={check ? joyWhite : joyPink}/>
                <SelectText check={check}>1</SelectText>
            </SelectBox_Left>
            <SelectBox_Right_1>
                <img src={fundingImg1}/>
            </SelectBox_Right_1>
        </SelectBox>
    )
} else if (props.id === "kind") {
    return (
        <SelectBox onClick={handleClick} check={check}>
            <SelectBox_Left>
                <img src={check ? kindWhite : kindPink}/>
                <SelectText check={check}>0</SelectText>
            </SelectBox_Left>
            <SelectBox_Right_2>
                <img src={fundingImg2}/>
            </SelectBox_Right_2>
        </SelectBox>
    )
} else if (props.id === "thanks") {
    return (
        <SelectBox onClick={handleClick} check={check}>
            <SelectBox_Left>
                <img src={check ? thanksWhite : thanksPink}/>
                <SelectText check={check}>2</SelectText>
            </SelectBox_Left>
            <SelectBox_Right_3>
                <img src={fundingImg3}/>
            </SelectBox_Right_3>
        </SelectBox>
    )
} else if (props.id === "uncomfortable") {
    return (
        <SelectBox onClick={handleClick} check={check}>
            <SelectBox_Left>
                <img src={check ? unWhite : unPink}/>
                <SelectText check={check}>3</SelectText>
            </SelectBox_Left>
            <SelectBox_Right_4>
                <img src={fundingImg4}/>
            </SelectBox_Right_4>
        </SelectBox>
    )
}
```

}

I want to get function in handleclick, if my selectId === emotionId is true and false setcheck toggle!
but i debug it, in handleclick selectId is faster than emotionId

so my console like (joy, undefined) => if i click kind => (kind, joy) like this. how can i solve this problem?? :(

Comment: Do you have property `selectId` in array `emotionCard`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the emotionCard in local state like this:

```
 const { emotionCard } = useSelector((state) => state.selectedReducer)
 const [emotionId, setEmotionId] = useState(emotionCard)

 useEffect(() => {
    if (emotionCard) setEmotionId(emotionCard.selectId)
 },[emotionCard])
```